# how to give anonymous user access to rpc api

Tags: javascript, web, odoo, rpc, anonymous

I need load model data via RPC in my JS.

If you do this

```
ajax.jsonRpc("/web/dataset/call_kw", 'call', {
            model: 'res.partner.category',
            method: 'search_read',
[...]
```

you get a SessionExpiredError because this controller is allowed only for authenticated users. To work around this you should define your custom controller every time you need something like this, which is a pity since the api are already there.

I have the following workaround at the moment:

JS:

```
ajax.jsonRpc("/web/dataset/call_kw_pub", 'call', {
            model: 'res.partner.category',
            method: 'search_read',
[...]
```

PY:

```
from openerp.addons.web.controllers.main import DataSet as DataSetBase

class DataSet(DataSetBase):
    @http.route([
        '/web/dataset/call_kw_pub',
        '/web/dataset/call_kw_pub/<path:path>'
    ], type='json', auth="public")
    def call_kw_pub(self, model, method, args, kwargs, path=None):
        if model not in ('partner.project.expertise', 'res.partner.category'):
            return http.request.not_found()
        return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
```

Model's access rights seems well handled by ACLs but to stay secure I'm just enabling this only for some models.

If this is not an issue at security level then we could think about allowing public access to standard controller. Any pointers?

This could be related to https://github.com/OCA/web/pull/402 too

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the question was in the title ;) I added a question mark at the end of text anyway.

Comment: You should read [this](https://www.odoo.com/page/responsible-disclosure). I don't think this belongs to SO.

Comment: @CZoellner this is not a bug, is a question on my workaround.

Comment: OK, but before the last edit "security hole" was in the title ;-)

Comment: RPC calls to custom controller method with `auth="public"` works, I just wanted this.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a module to provide this functionality, but anyone looking to do this quick and dirty can do so with the following code:

```
from openerp import models
from openerp.http import SessionExpiredException


class IrHttp(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'ir.http'

    def _auth_method_user(self):
        try:
            return super(IrHttp, self)._auth_method_user()
        except SessionExpiredException:
            return self._auth_method_public()
```

The above attempts a user authentication, then explicitly re-authenticates as the public user on a `SessionExpiredError`. This is the method used for authentication with an RPC session, and this is the error thrown when it fails. It also seems that this error is only thrown when auth fails for public user.

The naming of the error, however, makes me think that there are some possible connotations involved with using this hack that have not been fully identified yet.

What I can say is that your data will at least be secure with this, due to the default secure permissions of Odoo. I can also say that basic session functionality & tests all seem to work as normal, outside of a slightly different error than normal in the case of logging out in one tab then browsing in another.

What I cannot say is what unintended side-effects this has on edge cases with sessions. Prelim testing seemed fine, but there are definitely possible far-reaching consequences.

The module is being worked in on in [this pull request](https://github.com/OCA/web/pull/402), with a preliminary name of `web_session_allow_public`